# 400 bad request ("Unable to verify your data submission.") when Adding product to cart

Tags: cache, plugin-craftcommerce3, csrf, cloudflare, plugin-blitz

When a user tries to add something into the cart the following error appears:

> 400 bad request ("Unable to verify your data submission.")

```
2021-02-23 09:08:42 [-][-][fff512a7677a0fcf3272bd46e2fc3270][error][yii\web\HttpException:400] yii\web\BadRequestHttpException: Ihre Dateneingabe konnte nicht überprüft werden oder ist ungültig. in /path/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php:202
Stack trace:
#0 /path/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(138): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#1 /path/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(178): craft\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#2 /path/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(190): yii\base\Controller->runAction('update-cart', Array)
#3 /path/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\web\Controller->runAction('update-cart', Array)
#4 /path/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(274): yii\base\Module->runAction('commerce/cart/u...', Array)
#5 /path/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(577): craft\web\Application->runAction('commerce/cart/u...', Array)
#6 /path/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(253): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#7 /path/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#8 /path/www/index.php(32): yii\base\Application->run()
#9 {main}
2021-02-23 09:08:42 [-][-][fff512a7677a0fcf3272bd46e2fc3270][info][application] $_GET = [
    'p' => 'shop/product'
]

$_POST = [
    'action' => 'commerce/cart/update-cart'
    'redirect' => 'cbfe8c19da16c2536194408ca0939abfb84103fa6f70889e9e9bddc69715bd14purchase/cart'
    'qty' => '1'
```

It only happens when the browser is kept open for a long time. So I guess the token is renewed on the server but the old token is still in the browser.

Is there a way to remove the old token brom the client?

- The [Blitz](https://putyourlightson.com/plugins/blitz) plugin installed which caches the product page (But not the cart)
- There is also a Cloudflare in front of the webpage.

I guess these caching products add to this complexity. Cloudflare might be involved in this as well or probably the main contributor.

Anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSRF token is likely expiring. Since pages are cached with Blitz, you must  use some strategy to ensure that a fresh CSRF token is loaded into the page on each page that is statically served. The simplest way to do this is to use the [Dynamic Content](https://putyourlightson.com/plugins/blitz#dynamic-content) feature in Blitz, specifically `craft.blitz.csrfInput()`.

```
<form method="post">
   {{ craft.blitz.csrfInput() }}
   {# ... #}
 </form>
```